# DB2 operation Timeout or deadlock

Tags: database, jdbc, db2

I have an JDBC DB2error, operation timeout or deadlock , error number: -913.

scenario: Operation 1 performing update  a row in a table, which may take 2  minutes to complete the operation.

Operation 2 is trying to read the same row by quote number.

have an default locking CS( transaction_read_commited). 
I'm seeing  'operation Timeout or deadlock' after 60 seconds,
Is this timeout or deadlock scenario?

Is there any way that I can avoid deadlock by increasing connection timeout or lock timeout?

Suggestion around would be appreciate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the lock timeout by modifying the locktimeout parameter.

```
db2 update db cfg using locktimeout 180
```

This change the wait for 2 minutes. You can also put -1, to wait indefinitely.

For more information http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000329.html

The scenario is not a deadlock, because the operation 2 does not hold any resource, it is just trying to access the row being updated.

Comment: To check the current timeout:

```db2 get db cfg for [databasename]```

where [databasename] is the name of your database

Answer (score 0):

2 minutes a row?  What they heck are you trying to do?

In any case, yes, this is a timeout issue - your operation 2 is using the (assumedly) default timeout.  This can be set *per file*, and (at least for the iSeries, and probably for all versions of DB2) defaults to 60 seconds.

I'm not sure if this value can be set from SQL alone - you have to use the iSeries' native commands `CHGPF` or `CHGLF` (paramter `WAITFILE`/`WAITRECORD`, in *seconds*), if that's your platform (you didn't specify).  I don't really recommend it though - see if you can't get that update statement running faster... or, see about changing your architecture to allow somehow.

Comment: The operation could be loading a blob, and 2 minutes could be normal if the transfer is slow.